# Laravel: passing parameters to function?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass two parameters to a function in whereHas with Laravel because otherwhys it wont be able to use the `$businessid` but it's throwing an error, can anyone help?

Error:

> FatalThrowableError in HomeController.php line 16: Type error: Too few
>   arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\Business\User\HomeController::App\Http\Controllers\Business\User{closure}(),
>   1 passed in
>   C:\web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php
>   on line 938 and exactly 2 expected

Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Business\User;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Database\Frontend\Roleplay\Business\Businesses;
use App\Database\Frontend\User\Player;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getView(Request $request, $businessid)
    {
        $workerCount = Player::whereHas("roleplay", function($q2, $businessid) {
            $q2->where('business_id', $businessid);
        })->count();

        $workersWorkingCount = Player::where('currently_working', '1')->whereHas("roleplay", function($q2, $businessid) {
            $q2->where('business_id', $businessid);
        })->count();

        $workersOnlineCount = Player::where('online', '1')->whereHas("roleplay", function($q2, $businessid) {
            $q2->where('business_id', $businessid);
        })->count();

        $workersOfflineCount = Player::where('online', '0')->whereHas("roleplay", function($q2, $businessid) {
            $q2->where('business_id', $businessid);
        })->count();

        return view('business.home', compact(
            'workerCount',
            'workersWorkingCount',
            'workersOnlineCount',
            'workersOfflineCount'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This is how you can pass variable(s) to the function..

```
        $workerCount = Player::whereHas("roleplay", function($q2) use ($businessid) {
            $q2->where('business_id', $businessid);
        })->count();
```